# How to create two different players in a pong

Tags: javascript

I am creating a pong in Js, my pong is working because I used an artificial intelligence, only one player can play (I use the key 40 move down and the key 38 move up( var CODE_TOUCHE_BAS = 40;var CODE_TOUCHE_HAUT = 38);however i would like an other player(player 2 and would like to use the key 81 move up 65 move down(var CODE_Q = 81; var CODE_A =65;).I would like to put my TWO paddles in the AI function, here is my code for one player:

```
var CODE_TOUCHE_BAS = 40;
var CODE_TOUCHE_HAUT = 38;
var CODE_Q = 81;
var CODE_A = 65;
var ONE = 49;
var TWO = 50;
var ALLER_BAS = false;
var ALLER_HAUT = false;

var animerRaquetteA = function() {  

  if (ALLER_HAUT && positionYRaquetteA > 0)  

    positionYRaquetteA-=5;

  else if (ALLER_BAS && positionYRaquetteA < terrainLargeur - longueurRaquette)
    positionYRaquetteA+=5;
}

var animerRaquetteB_IA = function() {

 centreRaquetteB = positionYRaquetteB + longueurRaquette/2;
 if (directionHorizontaleBalle() == 'DROITE') {
    if (positionYBalle < centreRaquetteB) {
      // la position de la balle est sur l'écran, au dessus de celle de la raquette
      positionYRaquetteB -= incrementRaquetteB;
    } else if (positionYBalle > centreRaquetteB ) {
      //incrementRaquetteB = Math.random() * 1 + 4;
      positionYRaquetteB += incrementRaquetteB;
    } 
  } else {
    // se recentrer sur le terrain
    if ( centreRaquetteB > terrainLargeur / 2 ) {
      positionYRaquetteB -= incrementRaquetteB;
    } else if ( centreRaquetteB < terrainLargeur / 2 ) {
      positionYRaquetteB += incrementRaquetteB;
    }
  }
}
```

Someone can help me in order to put an other player using the keys 81 et 65

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs to gamedev.stackexchange

Comment: Still JS for me, no need to put in /gamedev/ ; even if it's for a game

Comment: Voting to close as this is not a specific programming question. This is "I want something so please do it and complete my program for me". Not a single word about what was attempted for it and what issues were encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Usually what you will do is two threads running simultaneously... But if this is a school project you can just do that player one do move then player 2... It will run so fast that you won't be able to see the time differences...

For example:

```
player1.move();
player2.move();
```